# Get symbol & contract from asset

Tags: smart-contract, development

I currently have an `asset` property that stores a value, i.e. `100 EOS` which could also be another token like `100 TLOS`.  Is there a way to extract the symbol and possibly the token contract from that asset?

I would like to use it to get the users balance of that specific token using `get_balance(token_contract, token_holder_name, symbol_code);` If that is indeed the right way of doing it?